# Automatically change text color to assure readability

Tags: javascript, text, colors, background

Users can set the background-color of a button through a textbox that accept RGB hexadecimal notation: `ff00ff`, `ccaa22`, etc. So I need to set the text color to the opposite. Not sure about the terminology (opposite color) but the idea is assure readability.

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664140/js-function-to-calculate-complementary-colour

Comment: what needs to be done is convert this RGB to HSL, complement the Hue(hue=hue+180mod360), and convert it back to RGB...
look for the conversion codes
http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript

Comment: @ smamatti && tejasva-dhyani: I am studying both solutions. Seems very promising. Thanks!

Comment: Actually that comes out to be 15's complement of the hex value...I don't know if it will work or not.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can invert the background color and use it as foreground color. The following algorithm produces results identical to the "Image > Adjustments > Invert" color command in Photoshop:

```js
function invertColor(hexTripletColor) {
    var color = hexTripletColor;
    color = color.substring(1);           // remove #
    color = parseInt(color, 16);          // convert to integer
    color = 0xFFFFFF ^ color;             // invert three bytes
    color = color.toString(16);           // convert to hex
    color = ("000000" + color).slice(-6); // pad with leading zeros
    color = "#" + color;                  // prepend #
    return color;
}
/*
 * Demonstration
 */
function randomColor() {
    var color;
    color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000); // integer between 0x0 and 0xFFFFFF
    color = color.toString(16);                    // convert to hex
    color = ("000000" + color).slice(-6);          // pad with leading zeros
    color = "#" + color;                           // prepend #
    return color;
}
$(function() {
    $(".demolist li").each(function() {
        var c1 = randomColor();
        var c2 = invertColor(c1);
        $(this).text(c1 + " " + c2).css({
            "color": c1,
            "background-color": c2
        });
    });
});
```

```css
body { font: bold medium monospace; }
.demolist { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; overflow: hidden; }
.demolist li { float: left; width: 5em; height: 5em; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<ul class="demolist">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that this is not a bullet-proof solution. Colors that are close to 50% brightness and/or saturation will not produce sufficient contrast.

[**Demo on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/f9Re3/)

Comment: damn that's one nice example!

Comment: Works really well for most colors but - as the note above suggests - not for all.  For grey (#7F7F7F) it returns (#808080), which is practically identical.  "Close but no cigar" :(

Answer (score 13):

Salaman's code is good but sometimes his inversion is not readable enough.
I use [YCbCr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#JPEG_conversion) and just change gray scale.

```
function invertColor(rgb) {
    var yuv = rgb2yuv(rgb);
    var factor = 180;
    var threshold = 100;
    yuv.y = clamp(yuv.y + (yuv.y > threshold ? -factor : factor));
    return yuv2rgb(yuv);
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1t0heesf/1/)

Comment: this algorithm fails on some colors. for example it fails for red (#FF0000). the text is not readable

Comment: seems that change the `factor` to 180 in `invertColor` function and it will look great!

Answer (score 5):

I linked another Question to this topic in the comments.
[JS function to calculate complementary colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664140/js-function-to-calculate-complementary-colour)

As Tejasva said you need to need to convert RGB to HSL, complement the Hue and convert it back.

I implemented the linked answer as a sample. Please upvote the original poster if this was helpful for you, because they provided the solution in fact.

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/pLZ89/2/

Comment: That is a sample/demo. I guess it should be easy for anyone to add a check if the color is black or white.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue once, and gathered information all over the internet also using Salman A answer, I came up with this function, it supports hex, rgb and rgba

```
var invertColor = function (color) {
            var hex   = '#';
            if(color.indexOf(hex) > -1){
                color = color.substring(1);           
                color = parseInt(color, 16);         
                color = 0xFFFFFF ^ color;            
                color = color.toString(16);           
                color = ("000000" + color).slice(-6); 
                color = "#" + color; 
            }else{
                color = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments).match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)/g);
                for (var i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
                    color[i] = (i === 3 ? 1 : 255) - color[i];
                }
                if(color.length === 4){
                    color = "rgba("+color[0]+","+color[1]+","+color[2]+","+color[3]+")";
                }else{
                    color = "rgb("+color[0]+","+color[1]+","+color[2]+")";
                }
            }         
            return color;
        }
```

but I don't think this is what you need, I found something more interesting, the below function will return white or black, it will decide witch one is more readable on the given color.

```
var getContrastYIQ = function (color){
            var hex   = '#';
            var r,g,b;
            if(color.indexOf(hex) > -1){
                r = parseInt(color.substr(0,2),16);
                g = parseInt(color.substr(2,2),16);
                b = parseInt(color.substr(4,2),16);
            }else{
                color = color.match(/\d+/g);
                r = color[0];
                g = color[1];
                b = color[2];
            }

            var yiq = ((r*299)+(g*587)+(b*114))/1000;
            return (yiq >= 128) ? 'black' : 'white';
        }
```

I don't take credit for any of this, I just got inspired and modified to my needs.

Sources: [YIQ function explained](https://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/)

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but IMO all text should either be light or dark.  Colored text is for links.

Here's a coffeescript function I've written to decide which to use:

```
is_light = (hex_color) ->
  c = hex_color.replace(/^#/,'')
  sum = parseInt(c[0]+c[1], 16)
  sum += parseInt(c[2]+c[3], 16)
  sum += parseInt(c[4]+c[5], 16)  
  log "sum is #{sum}"
  sum > 382.6
```

Comment: how did you come up with 382.6? :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var getContrastYIQ = function(color) {
  var hex = '#';
  var r, g, b;
  if (color.indexOf(hex) > -1) {
    r = parseInt(color.substr(1, 2), 16);
    g = parseInt(color.substr(3, 2), 16);
    b = parseInt(color.substr(5, 2), 16);
  } else {
    color = color.match(/\d+/g);
    r = color[0];
    g = color[1];
    b = color[2];
  }

  var yiq = ((r * 299) + (g * 587) + (b * 114)) / 1000;
  return (yiq >= 128) ? 'black' : 'white';
}
```

Thanks for the post ZetCoby!  Had to adjust your "color.substr(" array position to account for the initial '#'; then it worked great!  you could also use a color.replace('#',''); within the if block...

Answer (score 1):

You could use this simple schema to achieve that goal. Just convert the color from RGB to HSV form. You can use this [link](http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript) .
Then use this pseudo code;

```
rr = (color>>16)&0xFF;
gg = (color>>8)&0xFF;
bb = color & 0xFF;

someBrightColor = 0xFFFFFF;
someDarkColor = 0x000000;

hsvColor = rgbToHsv( rr, gg, bb );
//
//hsv is array: [h,s,v]...all values in [0,1]
//
//color is from dark range, if hsv < 0.5, so we need bright color to draw text, because    in dark color bright color 'will be more visible'.  
if( hsvColor[2] <= 0.5 )
  textColor = someBrightColor ;
//this is opposite case , when in more bright color, the dark color 'will be more visible'
else
  textColor = someDarkColor ;
```

Also you could divide [0,1] range into more parts. And instead of defining 2 colors (someBrightColor,someDarkColor) , define more colors. My suggested method is 'how bright is background color , thas text color must be dark, and vice versa'.

Comment: `rgbToHsv() function` accept decimal notation `[0, 255]` not hex. But assuming that I can make this translation, I really don't understand your pseudo-code. Please explain a little more. THX!

Comment: Very clear. OK. I will implement all and inform you back. Meanwhile an upvote for the effort, THX!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very small way to complement the hex value
//hex value like "aa00cc"

```
function complementHex(hexValue){
    var reqHex = "";
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        reqHex = reqHex + (15-parseInt(hexValue[i],16)).toString(16);
    }
    return reqHex;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same problem as the top answer above, i.e. Works really well for most colors but - as the note above suggests - not for all. For grey (#7F7F7F) it returns (#808080), which is practically identical. "Close but no cigar" :(

Answer (score 0):

```js
var getContrastYIQ = function(color) {
  var hex = '#';
  var r, g, b;
  if (color.indexOf(hex) > -1) {
    r = parseInt(color.substr(1, 2), 16);
    g = parseInt(color.substr(3, 2), 16);
    b = parseInt(color.substr(5, 2), 16);
  } else {
    color = color.match(/\d+/g);
    r = color[0];
    g = color[1];
    b = color[2];
  }

  var yiq = ((r * 299) + (g * 587) + (b * 114)) / 1000;
  return (yiq >= 128) ? 'black' : 'white';
}
```

```js
var getContrastYIQ = function(color) {
  var hex = '#';
  var r, g, b;
  if (color.indexOf(hex) > -1) {
    r = parseInt(color.substr(1, 2), 16);
    g = parseInt(color.substr(3, 2), 16);
    b = parseInt(color.substr(5, 2), 16);
  } else {
    color = color.match(/\d+/g);
    r = color[0];
    g = color[1];
    b = color[2];
  }

  var yiq = ((r * 299) + (g * 587) + (b * 114)) / 1000;
  return (yiq >= 128) ? 'black' : 'white';
}
```

Comment: Why duplicating the snippet? It would be great to add some supporting information.