# Is there an easy way to alter text colour based on background colour?

Tags: c#

I have a menu whereby a user can select colours, I display them like this:

[image: Plot Colours]

Because I write the colour codes in black, the dark blue background makes it difficult to read and the black is obviously completely hidden. Firstly, this isn't particularly important, the colour is what the user is interested in.

I could put the colour code in a separate box on a white background, but out of interest I wondered if there was some standard code to handle this or some easy method that could be applied to ensure that the text was always readable? If anyone could point me to a resource with any help it would be appreciated.

Comment: You could just invert all the bits of the background color. Works very well for many colors. But you get things like bright green (#00ff00) on magenta (#ff00ff) which will increase the suicide rate in your design team.

Comment: @thorstenmüller try that with #808080

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like it's not particularly straightforward.

Comment: Really, what is up with people downvoting. Don't just downvote, explain why you are. Remember what this site is for. Jeez Louise

Comment: @Family didn't down vote but i'd suggest its because you ask to be pointed to a resource (for the close vote) and its flagged C# (for the migration votes)

Comment: Whats your UI (ie WPF, Windows Forms)

Comment: Could you indclude the current code for the menu? Also, what kind of application is this? WPF? Winforms? ASP.NET? Something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just choose white if the colour is dark and black if it is light. Many applications do that, but I don't think there is standard implementation in .net libraries.

Try something like:

```
Color ForegroundForBackground(Color bg) {
    if(bg.R*2 + bg.G*7 + bg.B < 500)
        return Color.White;
    else
        return Color.Black;
}
```

You want to use white on pure blue, but not on pure gren and pure red because those look brighter. Tune the number to what looks sensible.

Edit: Since j.k. kindly provided the link to [Luminance (colorimetry)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance_%28colorimetry%29), I've changes the linear combination to match better (rounded the numbers to 1 digit, don't really need more). Though I suspect the coefficient for green might prove too large in testing.

Comment: +1 this is essentially how I'd do it though I might look up scaling factors such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance_%28colorimetry%29 rather than fudge my own

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible to adjust the color dynamically.

There are two parts to your question.  The first is changing the color and the second is determining what to change the color to.

The first is the more complex of the two.  I see two primary options:

1. Create your own control by inheriting from the existing control and override the appropriate functions to check the background in order to return a contrasting foreground color.
2. Create a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) and [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) your foreground colors to the return from the converter.

Of those two options, the value converter gives you the greatest portability across controls.  But it may or may not work with the UI technology that you're using.

The second step, determining what color to use, is a little bit more straightforward.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165107/how-do-i-invert-a-colour-color-c-net) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600295/automatically-change-text-color-to-assure-readability) are two SO questions that deal with reversing or inverting the color.  There are some edge cases based upon saturation that may not work the way you expect.  Alternatively, if your background colors are limited you can simply use a lookup table and be certain the results are what you expect.

Comment: I'd say the second was more complex, human perception is a tricky thing