# Using Javascript to create colour blend Hex

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to find some JS which when given a Hex code will generate 6 colours that match and dont clash.  I've seen this site: http://www.colorblender.com which does what i'm after but i need to do it myself so i can create colour schemes for my sites.

Please can you help, even if all you do is point out what JS the site is using and how to implement something similar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664140/js-function-to-calculate-complementary-colour

Comment: So why don't you check out the algorithm they are using? http://www.colorblender.com/static/js/blendercore.js is quite readable