# How can I generate the opposite color according to current color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I'm trying to create a color opposite of current color. I mean if current color is *black*, then I need to generate *white*.

Actually I have a text *(the color of this text is dynamic, its color can be made at random)*. That text is into a `div` and I need to set the opposite color of that text for the `background-color` of `div`. I would like that text be **clear** in the `div` *(color perspective)*.

> **The opposite color** means: Dark / Bright

I have the current color of text and I can pass it to this function:

```
var TextColor = #F0F0F0;    // for example (it is a bright color)

function create_opp_color(current color) {

    // create opposite color according to current color

}

create_opp_color(TextColor); // this should be something like "#202020" (or a dark color)
```

Is there any idea to create `create_opp_color()` function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664140/js-function-to-calculate-complementary-colour

Comment: Dark/Bright? So red (#FF0000) opposite is... Black (#000000)? For B/W "axis" is easy, but dealing with colors can be tricky if the desired goal is to get "contrast", and not the "complementary" color or something like that.

Comment: @miguel-svq Good point .. My goal is make that text readable *(color perspective)*, So if the color of text is *red*, then the color of background almost could be anything *black, white, blue* ..

Comment: There are really good modules for manipulating colors out there. Take e.g. a look at tinycolor (https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor) which has a `mostReadable` function. I think that's better than brewing one yourself.

Comment: why should we add padding with zeros, and why should we remove... someone explain..

Answer (score 352, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Production-ready **code on [GitHub](https://github.com/onury/invert-color).**

---

This is how I'd do it:

1. Convert HEX to RGB
2. Invert the R,G and B components
3. Convert each component back to HEX
4. Pad each component with zeros and output.

```js
function invertColor(hex) {
    if (hex.indexOf('#') === 0) {
        hex = hex.slice(1);
    }
    // convert 3-digit hex to 6-digits.
    if (hex.length === 3) {
        hex = hex[0] + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[1] + hex[2] + hex[2];
    }
    if (hex.length !== 6) {
        throw new Error('Invalid HEX color.');
    }
    // invert color components
    var r = (255 - parseInt(hex.slice(0, 2), 16)).toString(16),
        g = (255 - parseInt(hex.slice(2, 4), 16)).toString(16),
        b = (255 - parseInt(hex.slice(4, 6), 16)).toString(16);
    // pad each with zeros and return
    return '#' + padZero(r) + padZero(g) + padZero(b);
}

function padZero(str, len) {
    len = len || 2;
    var zeros = new Array(len).join('0');
    return (zeros + str).slice(-len);
}
```

Example Output:

[image]

**Advanced Version:**

This has a `bw` option that will decide whether to invert to black or white; so you'll get more contrast which is generally better for the human eye.

```js
function invertColor(hex, bw) {
    if (hex.indexOf('#') === 0) {
        hex = hex.slice(1);
    }
    // convert 3-digit hex to 6-digits.
    if (hex.length === 3) {
        hex = hex[0] + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[1] + hex[2] + hex[2];
    }
    if (hex.length !== 6) {
        throw new Error('Invalid HEX color.');
    }
    var r = parseInt(hex.slice(0, 2), 16),
        g = parseInt(hex.slice(2, 4), 16),
        b = parseInt(hex.slice(4, 6), 16);
    if (bw) {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023/112731
        return (r * 0.299 + g * 0.587 + b * 0.114) > 186
            ? '#000000'
            : '#FFFFFF';
    }
    // invert color components
    r = (255 - r).toString(16);
    g = (255 - g).toString(16);
    b = (255 - b).toString(16);
    // pad each with zeros and return
    return "#" + padZero(r) + padZero(g) + padZero(b);
}
```

Example Output:

[image]

Comment: This answer to the "opposite" question, setting color to foreground having a background color, wich is almost the same. Changing the fiddle accordingly to the original question can lead to low contrast color (without "bw") or to back and white backgrounds https://jsfiddle.net/cffcd5bj/5/ . Hope @stack adapt it to avoid undesired low contrast color pairs.

Comment: Good .. Just one thing, I've created an editor which supports rtl direction as well and there isn't any similar editor like that. How can I make it like a library? In other word, how can I make it downloadable like this `npm install myEditor --save`? Where should I locate my codes to be accessible through the internet using `npm` ?

Comment: @Shafizadeh if it's a final product, npm is not the place. If it's a JS/Node library/component do `npm publish`. See npm docs for this.

Comment: Getting inverse of color with such simple calculations (get symmetry according to 255) won't work if your color is like #808080. In this case, the reverse of the color is equal to itself

Comment: For those who need a php version of this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cad61140ce7b7ae935b62e7a79cf08c0845ad32c

Comment: I used the built in .padStart function for the return. return "#" + r.padStart(2, '0') + g.padStart(2, '0') + b.padStart(2, '0');  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: Great ! more than the code description is cool here is a python version of the same https://github.com/neps-in/awesome-snippies/blob/master/python/invert-color.py

Comment: can this work off color names ie: `floralwhite` or `orange`

Comment: @chovy you'd have to make a long list of known color names and map them to their hex values.

Comment: Just sharing this doesn't handle hex colors with alpha values.

Comment: go ahead and add that "feature".

Answer (score 64):

Simple and elegant.

```
function invertHex(hex) {
  return (Number(`0x1${hex}`) ^ 0xFFFFFF).toString(16).substr(1).toUpperCase()
}

invertHex('00FF00'); // Returns FF00FF
```

Comment: No idea what it does or how it works, but it's indeed simple and elegant :)

Comment: I would be really happy if someone would explain how it works.

Comment: @Ar2 
`Number(`0x1${hex}`)` First it takes the given hex (string) value and converts it to HEX
`^ 0xFFFFFF` it then does a bit-wise execution on that value with `0xFFFFFF` which I can only explain now like this, if you wanted to invert a number as quickly as possible eg. 3 > 7, 8 > 2, 1 > 9 etc. simply subtract with number with 10 and absolute it. That is what that part does except for HEX values.

The rest is basically formatting and dropping the first value which is an overflow of the equation.

Comment: Really nice and simple, but note that it "mirrors over the middle of the color", so colors close to the middle get a color very close to it. e.g. invertHex('808080'); produces '7F7F7F' which is almost the same color.

Comment: Impressive! Explanation:
Bitwise `^`  Sets each bit to 1 if only one of two bits is 1;
`toString(16)` The number will show as an hexadecimal value;
`substr(1)` Returns the result string, but skips the first item;
`toUpperCase()` This is very obvious.

Answer (score 33):

Simple way to achieve this with CSS:

```
mix-blend-mode: difference;
color:white;
```

Comment: A note of caution: mix-blend-mode is currently unsupported by !E or Microsoft Edge, among others, and depending on your use case, may be unlikely to fail gracefully.

Comment: when background is grey ,  the text is invisible .have you tested it?

Comment: How would that work? That and the invert solution mentioned elsewhere require more than one element since the inversion/blending is applied to the entire element. Speaking about the OP's question specifically, this answer doesn't even change the background (which is what the OP wanted).

Comment: I love this! Thanks 

Answer (score 17):

Pure CSS implementation of @Onur's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970186/146334) bw part.

```html
  <input type="color" oninput="['--r','--g','--b'].forEach((k,i)=>this.nextElementSibling.style.setProperty(k,parseInt(event.target.value.slice(1+i*2,3+i*2),16)))" />
 
  <div style="--r: 0; --g: 0; --b: 0; --c: calc(-1 * ((var(--r) * 0.299 + var(--g) * 0.587 + var(--b) * 0.114) - 186) * 255)">
    <div style="background-color: rgb(var(--r), var(--g), var(--b)); color: rgb(var(--c), var(--c), var(--c))">Test</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this is not a pure CSS, it include JS

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however the solution is pure CSS, the JS code you see is just for the sake of easy demonstration in a code snippet. If you don't believe, then delete the first line and edit the --r, --g, --b values in the outer div.

Answer (score 12):

How about, CSS `filter: invert(1)`, it has a decent [cross-browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/css-filters) and it work with text and images or whatever your content is.

For a black and white inverted color, add some more filters, `filter: saturate(0) grayscale(1) brightness(.7) contrast(1000%) invert(1)`

Here is a ColorPicker example (Notice the text color):

```js
const colorPicker = document.querySelector("input");
const background = document.querySelector("div");
const invertedText = document.querySelector("b");

colorPicker.oninput = (e) => {
  const color = e.target.value;
  background.style.background = color;
  invertedText.style.color = color;
  invertedText.innerText = color;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background: #333;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #378ad3;
}

b {
  /* Inverting the color ᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯ */
  filter: saturate(0) grayscale(1) brightness(.7) contrast(1000%) invert(1);
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <b>#378ad3</b>
  <input type="color" value="#378ad3"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is optimal on the front side.

Comment: This I have been looking for a very long time. Your solution of `saturate(0) grayscale(1) brightness(.7) contrast(1000%) invert(1)` was amazing.

Comment: This is so good and straightforward, The CSS just made it so easy to use no need for any js

Comment: For #b8b8b8 the text is unreadable.

Answer (score 7):

Watch out Accesibility (AA/AAA). Colour contrast by itself is useless. Really different colors can have no contrast at all for colour blind people.
IMHO a calculation for such a color could go like this:

(Use "HLS" for simplicity)

- Rotate Hue 180º to get the (maybe useless) maximal color contrast
- Calculate Brightness Difference.
- ( Calculate Colour Difference... unnecesary, it's maximal or almost )
- Calculate Contrast Ratio.
- If the resulting color complies the requirements calculation ends, if not, loop:

  - If Brightness Difference is not enought increase or
    decrese calculated color luminosity (L) by a certain amount or ratio (up or
    down depending on the original colour brightness: > or < than the mid
    value)
  - Check if it complies your requirements, if it does calculation ends.
  - if luminosity can be increased (or decrased) any more there is no valid color to comply the requirements, just try black and white, take "the best one" of those (probably the one with bigger contrast ratio) and end.

Answer (score 4):

In my understanding of your question, by opposite color you mean inverted color.

```
InvertedColorComponent = 0xFF - ColorComponent
```

So for the color red (#FF0000) this means:
    R = 0xFF or 255
    G = 0x00 or 0
    B = 0x00 or 0

inverted color red (#00FFFF) is:

```
R = 0xFF - 0xFF = 0x00 or 255 - 255 = 0
G = 0xFF - 0x00 = 0xFF or 255 - 0 = 255
B = 0xFF - 0x00 = 0xFF or 255 - 0 = 255
```

Another examples:

Black (#000000) becomes White (#FFFFFF).

Orange (#FFA500) becomes #005AFF

Comment: I would have used "inverse" too, but remember that "opposite" can also mean "opposite on the colour wheel".

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple function that invert an hexadecimal color

```
const invertColor = (col) => {
col = col.toLowerCase();
  const colors = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f']
  let inverseColor = '#'
  col.replace('#','').split('').forEach(i => {
    const index = colors.indexOf(i)
    inverseColor += colors.reverse()[index]
  })
  return inverseColor
}
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/supah/pen/vYBqbNK)

Answer (score 2):

Simply flipping background color to text color won't work with some middle range values, e.g. `0x808080`. I had tried with shifting the color values instead - `(v + 0x80) % 0x100`. See a demo [here](https://codepen.io/jason_zhuyx/pen/VyGRBd).

Agreeing with the comment from [miguel-svq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35969938/4922856) - although expecting to see more detailed algorithms for each calculation step.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to convert a **HEX** color using the snippets

```
function invertColor(color) {
      return '#' + ("000000" + (0xFFFFFF ^ parseInt(color.substring(1),16)).toString(16)).slice(-6);
  }
```

Comment: This is good, it is a quick method to get a practically usable invert

Answer (score 1):

Function to Invert Color of Element. Gets the luminosity of each and if they are close, inverts text color.

```
function adjustColor(element) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    var background = new Color(style['background-color']);
    var text = new Color(style['color']);
    if (Math.abs(background.luma - text.luma) < 100) {
        element.style.color = text.inverted.toString();
    }
}
```

The Color "Class" below. Accepts hex, rgb, rgba (even with percents), and can output to either one as well.  Explorer will need polyfills for [String.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and [String.startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and the interpolated string in the toString() method will need to be modified using concat instead.

```
const Color = (function () {
    function toHex(num, padding) { return num.toString(16).padStart(padding || 2); }
    function parsePart(value) {
        var perc = value.lastIndexOf('%');
        return perc < 0 ? value : value.substr(0, perc);
    }
    function Color(data) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            this[0] = arguments[0];
            this[1] = arguments[1];
            this[2] = arguments[2];
            if (arguments.length > 3) { this[3] = arguments[3]; }
        } else if (data instanceof Color || Array.isArray(data)) {
            this[0] = data[0];
            this[1] = data[1];
            this[2] = data[2];
            this[3] = data[3];
        } else if (typeof data === 'string') {
            data = data.trim();
            if (data[0] === "#") {
                switch (data.length) {
                    case 4:
                        this[0] = parseInt(data[1], 16); this[0] = (this[0] << 4) | this[0];
                        this[1] = parseInt(data[2], 16); this[1] = (this[1] << 4) | this[1];
                        this[2] = parseInt(data[3], 16); this[2] = (this[2] << 4) | this[2];
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        this[3] = parseInt(data.substr(7, 2), 16);
                    //Fall Through
                    case 7:
                        this[0] = parseInt(data.substr(1, 2), 16);
                        this[1] = parseInt(data.substr(3, 2), 16);
                        this[2] = parseInt(data.substr(5, 2), 16);
                        break;
                }
            } else if (data.startsWith("rgb")) {
                var parts = data.substr(data[3] === "a" ? 5 : 4, data.length - (data[3] === "a" ? 6 : 5)).split(',');
                this.r = parsePart(parts[0]);
                this.g = parsePart(parts[1]);
                this.b = parsePart(parts[2]);
                if (parts.length > 3) { this.a = parsePart(parts[3]); }
            }
        }
    }
    Color.prototype = {
        constructor: Color,
        0: 255,
        1: 255,
        2: 255,
        3: 255,
        get r() { return this[0]; },
        set r(value) { this[0] = value == null ? 0 : Math.max(Math.min(parseInt(value), 255), 0); },
        get g() { return this[1]; },
        set g(value) { this[1] = value == null ? 0 : Math.max(Math.min(parseInt(value), 255), 0); },
        get b() { return this[2]; },
        set b(value) { this[2] = value == null ? 0 : Math.max(Math.min(parseInt(value), 255), 0); },
        get a() { return this[3] / 255; },
        set a(value) { this[3] = value == null ? 255 : Math.max(Math.min(value > 1 ? value : parseFloat(value) * 255, 255), 0); },
        get luma() { return .299 * this.r + .587 * this.g + .114 * this.b; },
        get inverted() { return new Color(255 - this[0], 255 - this[1], 255 - this[2], this[3]); },
        toString: function (option) {
            if (option === 16) {
                return '#' + toHex(this.r) + toHex(this.g) + toHex(this.b) + (this[3] === 255 ? '' : toHex(this[3]));
            } else if (option === '%') {
                if (this.a !== 1) {
                    return `rgba(${this.r / 255 * 100}%, ${this.b / 255 * 100}%, ${this.g / 255 * 100}%, ${this.a / 255})`;
                } else {
                    return `rgb(${this.r / 255 * 100}%, ${this.b / 255 * 100}%, ${this.g / 255 * 100})%`;
                }
            } else {
                if (this.a !== 1) {
                    return `rgba(${this.r}, ${this.b}, ${this.g}, ${this.a})`;
                } else {
                    return `rgb(${this.r}, ${this.b}, ${this.g})`;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return Color;
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Python alternatives of Onur's answer:

```
def hex_to_rgb(value):
    value = value.lstrip('#')
    lv = len(value)
    return tuple(int(value[i:i + lv // 3], 16) for i in range(0, lv, lv // 3))

def invertColor(color, bw=False):
    # strip the # from the beginning
    color = color.lstrip('#')

    # convert the string into hex
    color = int(color, 16)

    # invert the three bytes
    # as good as substracting each of RGB component by 255(FF)
    comp_color = 0xFFFFFF ^ color

    # convert the color back to hex by prefixing a #
    comp_color = "#%06X" % comp_color

    rgb_color = hex_to_rgb(comp_color)
    
    if (bw):
        # http://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023/112731
        bw_value = rgb_color[0]*0.299 + rgb_color[0]*0.587 + rgb_color[0]*0.114
        if (bw_value>186):
            comp_color = "#FFFFFF"
        else:
            comp_color = "#000000"

    # return the result
    return comp_color

color = "#fffff1"

print invertColor(color, bw=True)
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question as it was tagged HTML and Javascript

Answer (score 0):

For Typescript lovers, here what I use:

```
invertHex(hex: string) {
  if (hex.indexOf('#') === 0) {
    hex = hex.slice(1);
  }

  if (hex.length != 6) {
    console.warn('Hex color must be six hex numbers in length.');
    return '#' + hex;
  }

  hex = hex.toUpperCase();
  const splitNum = hex.split('');
  let resultNum = '';
  const simpleNum = 'FEDCBA9876'.split('');
  const complexNum = {
    A: '5', B: '4', C: '3', D: '2', E: '1', F: '0'
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(Number(splitNum[i]))) {
      resultNum += simpleNum[splitNum[i]];
    } else if (complexNum[splitNum[i]]) {
      resultNum += complexNum[splitNum[i]];
    } else {
      console.warn('Hex colors must only include hex numbers 0-9, and A-F');
      return '#' + hex;
    }
  }

  return '#' + resultNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getContrastColor(color) {
  var hex = color.replace(/#/, '');
  var red = parseInt(hex.substr(0, 2), 16);
  var green = parseInt(hex.substr(2, 2), 16);
  var blue = parseInt(hex.substr(4, 2), 16);

  var luminance = (0.2126  red + 0.7152  green + 0.0722 * blue) / 255;
  return luminance > 0.5 ? '#000000' : '#ffffff';
}

var contrastColor = getContrastColor("#FFFFFF");
console.log(contrastColor);
```

Comment: That is not the correct formula for luminance, the tuples need to be normalized 0.0-1.0 nd then linearized ^2.2, and then, the threshold is ~0.36