# How to dynamically change text colour based on dynamically changing background colour

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am setting up a new website and need my text to change colour based on the ever-changing background colours in order to maintain contrast. I have scoured the web for answers that don't involve Sass, but none have worked...

I have tried some JavaScript, but they work only when the background is a fixed colour that you change manually.

My Current File:
https://codepen.io/jonathanlee/pen/wZXvRY

```
var color = function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = color(); //() to execute the function!
}, 3000);

var ww = function isDarkColor(rgb) {
  return Math.round((
    parseInt(rgb[0], 10) * 299 +
    parseInt(rgb[1], 10) * 587 +
    parseInt(rgb[2], 10) * 114) / 1000) <= 140
}

if (ww <= 140) {
  document.getElementById("test").style.color = '#fff';
} else {
  document.getElementById("test").style.color = '#000';
}
```

One of the other solutions I've tried, but didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/QkSva/

```
function isDark(color) {
  var match = /rgb\((\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+)\)/.exec(color);
  return (match[1] & 255) +
    (match[2] & 255) +
    (match[3] & 255) <
    3 * 256 / 2;
}
$('div').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).css("background-color"))
  $(this).css("color", isDark($(this).css("background-color")) ? 'white' : 'black');
});
```

The real-life example is an alternate homepage on the website I'm working on, https://nepmelbourne.com/q. I have got a dynamic background, but there are some colours that don't contrast well against my white text.

Comment: Why don't add a minor text shadow like on subtitles?

Comment: Who is calling `isDarkColor`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it would be to set opposite color of background color to text as follows,

```js
function invertColor(hex, bw) {
    if (hex.indexOf('#') === 0) {
      hex = hex.slice(1);
    }
    // convert 3-digit hex to 6-digits.
    if (hex.length === 3) {
      hex = hex[0] + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[1] + hex[2] + hex[2];
    }
    if (hex.length !== 6) {
      throw new Error('Invalid HEX color.');
    }
    var r = parseInt(hex.slice(0, 2), 16),
      g = parseInt(hex.slice(2, 4), 16),
      b = parseInt(hex.slice(4, 6), 16);
    if (bw) {
      // http://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023/112731
      return (r * 0.299 + g * 0.587 + b * 0.114) > 186 ?
        '#000000' :
        '#FFFFFF';
    }
    // invert color components
    r = (255 - r).toString(16);
    g = (255 - g).toString(16);
    b = (255 - b).toString(16);
    // pad each with zeros and return
    return "#" + padZero(r) + padZero(g) + padZero(b);
  }

  function padZero(str, len) {
    len = len || 2;
    var zeros = new Array(len).join('0');
    return (zeros + str).slice(-len);
  }

  var color = function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    var bgColor = color();
    var textColor = invertColor(bgColor,true);
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = bgColor; //() to execute the function!
    document.getElementById("test").style.color = textColor;
  }, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="test">This is some text</div>
```

Opposite color code taken from [How can I generate the opposite color according to current color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969656/how-can-i-generate-the-opposite-color-according-to-current-color/35970186)

Added an extra parameter bw to invertColor(), if bw is set to true the text color will be black if background is bright and vice versa.

Comment: thanks for the great code! I was wondering, however, if it is possible to just keep the text either black or white...

Comment: That is amazing! Thanks so much! The last thing I was trying to work out was if it is possible to control the speed at which the colours change, ie. every 3000ms it changes colour smoothly...