# How to display current HEX code of dynamically changing page background?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have my page constantly update and display the current HEX code of the background colour, which changes colour every 3000ms (code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772303/how-to-dynamically-change-text-colour-based-on-dynamically-changing-background-c)). I've already tried using innerHTML and eventListener, but can't quite get it. This is the code for my page now:

```
<body class="index-page" id="body" style="user-select: none; cursor: none">
    <div class="cursor"></div>
    <div class="wrapper" onmousedown='return false;' onselectstart='return false;'>
        <div id="container" style="background-color: transparent !important;"></div>
        <main class="" id="content" style="">
            <div class="heroindex text-center" style="">
                <h1 class="white texth ctabtn" style="background-color: transparent; font-weight: bold; color: black;" id="name">Jonathan Lee</h1>
            </div>

        </main>
        <div id="intro" style="height: 500px; text-align: center">
            <h2>Current Colour</h2>
            <p id="testval"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function invertColor(hex, bw) {
            if (hex.indexOf('#') === 0) {
                hex = hex.slice(1);
            }
            // convert 3-digit hex to 6-digits.
            if (hex.length === 3) {
                hex = hex[0] + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[1] + hex[2] + hex[2];
            }
            if (hex.length !== 6) {
                throw new Error('Invalid HEX color.');
            }
            var r = parseInt(hex.slice(0, 2), 16),
                g = parseInt(hex.slice(2, 4), 16),
                b = parseInt(hex.slice(4, 6), 16);
            if (bw) {
                // http://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023/112731
                return (r * 0.299 + g * 0.587 + b * 0.114) > 186 ?
                    '#000000' :
                    '#FFFFFF';
            }
            // invert color components
            r = (255 - r).toString(16);
            g = (255 - g).toString(16);
            b = (255 - b).toString(16);
            // pad each with zeros and return
            return "#" + padZero(r) + padZero(g) + padZero(b);
        }

        function padZero(str, len) {
            len = len || 2;
            var zeros = new Array(len).join('0');
            return (zeros + str).slice(-len);
        }

        var color = function getRandomColor() {
            var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
            var color = '#';
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
            }
            return color;
        }
    

        setInterval(function() {
            var bgColor = color();
            var textColor = invertColor(bgColor, true);
            document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = bgColor; // ensure that all following ID calls are sequential
            document.getElementById("name").style.color = textColor;
            document.getElementById("intro").style.color = textColor;
        }, 3000);

    </script>
</body>
```

I'm after the current HEX code to be displayed in the p element with ID "testval".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
document.getElementById("testval").innerHTML = bgColor;
```

after the other `document.getElementById()`s...

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}


setInterval(function() {
  var bgColor = getRandomColor();
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
  document.getElementById("testval").innerHTML = bgColor;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="testval">...</p>
```

Comment: Wowww, how did I overlook that! Cheers for answering my question so quickly mate, appreciate it :))