# is there a way to generate foreground (text and navigation) contrasting colour to the random background colour

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a random background generator that picks random colors from the array and generate a linear gradient for the background.

Can someone please help me with codes as I am not getting any idea how to write the codes to generate contrasting foreground (text and navigation).

I need that my text-font color and naviagtion bar can automatically change to a contrast color based on the background color.

My current javascript codes

```
function GetValue() {
  var myarray = new Array("#ff0000", "#ffe100", "#95ff00", "#2c8d94", "#ad6428","#d46317", "#0cc27c");

  var randomColor1 = myarray.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length),1)[0];
  var randomColor2 = myarray.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length), 1)[0];

  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = randomColor1 + randomColor2;
  return [randomColor1, randomColor2];
}

var styles = ["to right", "to bottom right", "-90deg"];

function applyChanges(randomColor1, randomColor2) {
  var randomColor1 = GetValue();
  var randomColor2 = GetValue();
  var bg = "";
  var style = Math.floor(Math.random() * styles.length);
  bg = "linear-gradient(" + styles[style] + "," + randomColor1 + "," + randomColor2 + ")";
  $("body").css("background", bg);
  $("#myInput").text(bg);
}

function changeBg() {
  var [randomColor1, randomColor2] = GetValue();
  console.log(randomColor1, randomColor2);
  applyChanges(randomColor1, randomColor2);
}
```

My current HTML codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>STARTING NOW</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header_section">
      <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <img
        src="d8282202e8adb36a20e88d27ffc3b15e.jpg"
        alt="headerimage"
        class="image"
      />
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text"><h3>I AM RAJ JAIN</h3></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div>
      <img src="IMG_3260.jpg" class="rounded-circle" alt="profile pic" />
    </div>

    <br />

    <div id="description">
      <h5>I am a full-stack web developer based in Melbourne, Australia</h5>
    </div>

    <div>
      <hr class="line1" />
    </div>

    <div id="description">
      <h3>Here's what i have done so far</h3>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <img src="afcg.png" id="evidence1" alt="afcg work" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3 id="descrip1">Member's directory - Dynamic Wordpress Website</h3>
          <p id="descrip2">
            This is the directory I created during my IT Internship at Advanced
            Fibre Cluster Geelong. This webpage is based on Wordpress.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <img src="wordminer.png" id="evidence1" alt="afcg work" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3 id="descrip1">Wordminer app</h3>
          <p id="descrip2">This is the Web app i created using html and css.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>


    <div>
      <hr class="line1" />
    <div/>

    <div id="description">
      <h3>My Photos</h3>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <img src="geometric-1202611_640.jpg" alt="1st image" style="width: 200px; height: auto; padding: 3%;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img src="gingham-1525372_640.jpg" alt="2nd image" style="width: 200px; height: auto; padding: 3%;"  />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img src="gold-992079_640.jpg" alt="3rd image" style="width: 200px; height: auto; padding: 3%;"  />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img src="space-4257486_640.jpg" alt="4th image" style="width: 200px; height: auto; padding: 3%;"  />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="changeBg();" />
    <p id="message" ></p>
    <p id="myInput"></p>


<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script
src=”https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
integrity=”sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=”
crossorigin=”anonymous”></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Text font color can be inverted to white or black depending on hex color value. You will find a good explained solution to this issue here:

[Invert to white or black depending on background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969656/how-can-i-generate-the-opposite-color-according-to-current-color)

I share you the code inside a working function.

```
function invertColor(hex, bw) {
  if (hex.indexOf('#') === 0) {
     hex = hex.slice(1);
  }
  // convert 3-digit hex to 6-digits.
  if (hex.length === 3) {
     hex = hex[0] + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[1] + hex[2] + hex[2];
  }
  if (hex.length !== 6) {
     throw new Error('Invalid HEX color.');
  }
  var r = parseInt(hex.slice(0, 2), 16),
      g = parseInt(hex.slice(2, 4), 16),
      b = parseInt(hex.slice(4, 6), 16);
  if (bw) {
      // http://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023/112731
      return (r * 0.299 + g * 0.587 + b * 0.114) > 186
        ? '#000000'
        : '#FFFFFF';
  }
  // invert color components
  r = (255 - r).toString(16);
  g = (255 - g).toString(16);
  b = (255 - b).toString(16);
  // pad each with zeros and return
  return "#" + padZero(r) + padZero(g) + padZero(b);
}

function padZero(str, len) {
  len = len || 2;
  var zeros = new Array(len).join('0');
  return (zeros + str).slice(-len);
}
```

EDITED:
Copy this code into your javascript file. Inside your "applyChanges()" function, add this line of code:

```
$("body").css("color", invertColor(randomColor1[1], true));
```

You can send the second param as **false**, but you are creating gradients and change the font color with opposites, could generate a color that is not kind for reading. The first param I chose is the darkest color in your gradients, but you can test sending the other color in the array.

I hope this solve your problem!

Comment: Hi Sky games inc,
Actually I also found the above the example but I am not getting how to merge these codes in my program.  how to make use of these codes ??

I have create random background program so where and how should i add these codes ??

Comment: I add a better explanation to use this code. You will be able to use it easyly and change thinks to get the result you want. Best Regards!