# How can I calculate the opposite luminosity of a color in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to programatically determine the inverse of a user-provided color in CSS in order to provide an aesthetically pleasing experience switching from light mode and dark mode in the browser.

Is this achievable? Perhaps it might take a dash of Javascript to modify a CSS variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate the opposite color according to current color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969656/how-can-i-generate-the-opposite-color-according-to-current-color)

Comment: Are you interested in getting the opposite luminosity, which is mentioned in the title, or in getting the inverse of the color, which you mention in your text?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean getting the inverse color.
Finding a complementary color is very simple in the RGB model. For any given color, for example, red (#FF0000), you need to find the color, which, after being added to red, creates white (0xFFFFFF).
Naturally, all you need to do, is subtract red from white and get cyan

(0xFFFFFF - 0xFF0000 = 0x00FFFF).

Hope I helped, good luck.

[image]