# Is it possible to set text color (white or black) based on background (any color & color format)?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, less, background-color

I need set text color based on background (**text color should be black or white**). **Background in my app could have any color & color format**. I was looking for a couple approaches, but for me non of them were perfect:

1. mix-blend-mode (seems to me uncontrollable, I didn't come up with solution, where my conditions would be accomplished)

[image]

2. filter() css (from my perspective works bad for text, I see pixels when highlight text)
   [image]
3. less function contrast (color: contrast(@backgroundColor, #000, #fff, 80%);) (it could be perfect solution, but I don't know how to update @backgroundColor, for some reason less.modifyvars doesn't work in my angular app (less in not defined) )
4. js (I can't find angular lib which will be converting all official color formats to rgb. I need rgb to calculate what color use white or black)

Comment: Your question is to set a color of a font? What is wrong with 'color: black'? What do you mean with converting colors to rgb? It's a simple formula to go from hex (#123456) to rgb..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invert CSS font-color depending on background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981763/invert-css-font-color-depending-on-background-color)

Comment: @Wimanicesir I meant that my component can use any color format. So user can set "red", hsl(150 30% 60%) (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#syntax).. and all this formats I should support. I need them to be converted in rba

Comment: @tacoshy Unfortunately, no, because there are hardcoded colors (red & aqua), I need something dynamic

Comment: you dont have to hard code the colors when using that `mix-blend-Mode` method.

Comment: for hex colors you could use this function https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970186/17447

Comment: Just always convert to hex or rgb: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-color-names-to-hexcode-using-javascript/

Comment: @tacoshy could you help me please to achieve that text will be white on red background and black on white background https://jsfiddle.net/dh5yeusj/10/?

Comment: @Kvasimodo this currently can't be done with CSS alone, you'll need to use javascript for this to work solidly. There is a new CSS function that solves this, but it isn't yet supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-contrast

Answer (score 0):

there're a few functions that give you the luminance of a color, e.g.

```
  isLight(color: string) { //<--color in the way '#RRGGBB
    if (rgb.length == 7) {
      const rgb = [
        parseInt(color.substring(1, 3), 16),
        parseInt(color.substring(3, 5), 16),
        parseInt(color.substring(5), 16),
      ];
      const luminance =
        (0.2126 * rgb[0]) / 255 +
        (0.7152 * rgb[1]) / 255 +
        (0.0722 * rgb[2]) / 255;
      return luminance > 0.5;
    }
    return false
  }
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sqwgj3?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

NOTE: Some time ago I recreate javascript library colors in this another [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztjvu9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)