# JavaScript Complementary Colors

Tags: javascript, colors

I am trying to get complementary colors with JavaScript, but I can't find what I need. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664140/js-function-to-calculate-complementary-colour/1664186#1664186), but for values like `#000000`, and `#142814`, they just return themselves. For the first value, I feel like it would make sense to get `#FFFFFF`. Is there a function which would work like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the difference from 2<sup>24</sup> - 1 and the value of the color and for shorter colors the difference of 2<sup>12</sup> - 1 and the value of the color.

```js
function getComplementaryColor(color) {
    var c = color.slice(1),
        i = parseInt(c, 16),
        v = ((1 << 4 * c.length) - 1 - i).toString(16);

    while (v.length < c.length) {
        v = '0' + v;
    }
    return '#' + v;
}

console.log(getComplementaryColor('#142814'));
console.log(getComplementaryColor('#000000'));
console.log(getComplementaryColor('#111111'));
console.log(getComplementaryColor('#ffffff'));
console.log(getComplementaryColor('#39f'));
console.log(getComplementaryColor('#000'));
console.log(getComplementaryColor('#111'));
console.log(getComplementaryColor('#fff'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```