# How to generate randomly colors that is easily recognizable from each other?

Tags: c#, winforms, random, colors

I want to generate random colors for a graphic chart but what I tried is not recognizable and generated color are similar to each other generally. Is it possible to create such colors?

My method:

```
    public Color[] GenerateColors(int n)
    {
        Color[] colors = new Color[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int R = rnd.Next(0, 250);
            int G = rnd.Next(0, 250);
            int B = rnd.Next(0, 250);

            Color color = Color.FromArgb(R, G, B);
            colors[i] = color;
        }
        return colors;
    }
```

Comment: In that case, you better don't use random, but some sort of pattern

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374550/how-to-compare-color-object-and-get-closest-color-in-an-color/27375621?s=1|1.0441#27375621) for a discussion of Color Distance. Also do look at the [`KnownColors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx)!

Comment: There's some ideas here http://martin.ankerl.com/2009/12/09/how-to-create-random-colors-programmatically/ and here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044/algorithm-to-randomly-generate-an-aesthetically-pleasing-color-palette

Comment: Thanks, @OldBoyCoder the article explains the problem well and gives a good solution

Comment: Depending on how many colors you need, you could just hardcode them. Cynthia Brewer's [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) is widely used for generating easily-distinguishable color schemes for the presentation of data. Pick the nature of your data, pick the number of data classes, and finally pick a color scheme/palette of your preference. Copy those hex values, store them in a list or array, profit!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `RandomColors` class that combines the suggestions from [Taw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3152130/taw) and [OldBoyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6018839/oldboycoder). Based on how many color you want to generate the method `Generate` either picks from the `KnownColors` or generates random new colors where it used the last color as a mix color.

```
public class RandomColors
{
    static Color lastColor = Color.Empty;

    static KnownColor[] colorValues = (KnownColor[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));

    static Random rnd = new Random();
    const int MaxColor = 256;
    static RandomColors()
    {
        lastColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(MaxColor), rnd.Next(MaxColor), rnd.Next(MaxColor));
    }

    public static Color[] Generate(int n)
    {
        var colors = new Color[n];
        if (n <= colorValues.Length)
        {
            // known color suggestion from TAW
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234131/how-to-generate-randomly-colors-that-is-easily-recognizable-from-each-other#comment61999963_37234131
            var step = (colorValues.Length-1) / n;
            var colorIndex = step;
            step = step == 0 ? 1 : step; // hacky
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++ )
            {
                colors[i] = Color.FromKnownColor(colorValues[colorIndex]);
                colorIndex += step;
            }
        } else
        {
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                colors[i] = GetNext();
            }
        }

        return colors;
    }

    public static Color GetNext()
    {
        // use the previous value as a mix color as demonstrated by David Crow
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/43235/578411
        Color nextColor = Color.FromArgb(
            (rnd.Next(MaxColor) + lastColor.R)/2, 
            (rnd.Next(MaxColor) + lastColor.G)/2, 
            (rnd.Next(MaxColor) + lastColor.B)/2
            );
        lastColor = nextColor;
        return nextColor;
    }
}
```