# How to generate random pastel (or brighter) color in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, colors, rgb, color-palette

**Question:** Is there is any way (in JS) to create a random color code using just *bright colors*, or *pastel colors*?

I am building a simple website that gives a random quote when I click a button, and with that, the background color changes. The thing is that sometimes the background color is too dark and the font is black, and consequently the person can't read the quote.

I found this code to generate a random color. I tried to edit to get only the strings `A` to `F`, but no success:

```
'#'+((1<<24)*(Math.random()+1)|0).toString(16).substr(1)
```

Comment: Use `hsl()` color and randomize just the Hue after finding optimal Saturation and Luminosity values https://jsfiddle.net/sva8ckpy/

Comment: I'd guess `'#'+((1<<24)*(Math.random()+1)|0xc0c0c0).toString(16).substr(1)` might do the trick -- it should constrain every component to being in the range 0xc0-0xff but I don't know javascript so really anything at all could happen.  0x808080 allows more variation, but it might be too much.  If you need more flexibility then you'll want one of the more complete answers given by people who probably know javascript.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

#### HSL Colors

Using [HSL Colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#hsl()) colors may be the easiest. HSL color values are specified in CSS as

```
hsl( hue, saturation%, lightness%)
```

where `hue` is in range 0-360 (without a unit marker when using degrees), and both `saturation` and `lightness` are percentages 0-100 with a trailing `%` sign.

**Note**

- "Bright" colors refer to the colors of an RGB color wheel formed by starting at red and then blending pure red into green, pure green into blue, and finally pure blue back into red again.
- In HSL color space, bright colors are represented by a hue based on their position on the color wheel with `100%` saturation and a lightness value of `50%`:

  hue `0` ▶ [image: HSL saturated color circle] ◀ hue `360`
  saturation: `100%`
  lightness: `50%`

- Colors blend with white - and become more "pastel" as lightness increases above `50%`. A lightness value of `100%` creates white regardless of what the values of hue and saturation are.
- Colors blend with grey as the saturation *decreases* and become more washed  out depending on how low the saturation gets. A saturation value of `0%` creates a grey-scale tone based on lightness alone.
- Colors blend with black as lightness decreases below `50%`. A lightness value of `0%` creates black no matter what the hue and saturation values are.

**Warning**

The human eye is least sensitive to the color blue. Black text on a blue background - or blue over black - is harder to read in comparison to other colors. If this becomes an issue for random color selection, example 2 shows one way to compensate.

---

Example 1: Some random pastel colors with **saturation** in range `25-95%` and **lightness** in range `85-95%`:

```js
function getColor(){ 
  return "hsl(" + 360 * Math.random() + ',' +
             (25 + 70 * Math.random()) + '%,' + 
             (85 + 10 * Math.random()) + '%)'
}


// Generate 20 colors
for( var i = 20; i--; ){
  var item = document.createElement('div')
  item.style.cssText = `
    display:inline-block; 
    padding: 2em;
    margin:5px; 
    border-radius:50%;
    background: ${getColor()};
  `
  document.body.appendChild(item);
}
```

---

Example 2: This example demonstrates adjusting colors for the eye's lack of sensitivity to blue. It generates a boxed set of letters colored with hues in the range 0 to 340 presented on a black background.

```js
"use strict";

// individual letter classes:
function letterCSS(letter, i, length, blueBoost) {
    let hue = Math.floor( i/length * 341); // between 0 and 340
    let saturation = 100;
    let lightness = 50;

    // color adjustment:
    if( blueBoost && hue > 215 && hue < 265) {
         const gain = 20;
         let blueness = 1 - Math.abs( hue-240)/25;
         let change  = Math.floor( gain * blueness);
         lightness += change;
         saturation -= change;
    }
    let hsl = `hsl(${hue}, ${saturation}%, ${lightness}%)`;

  return `.${letter} {
  color: ${hsl};
  border-color: ${hsl};
  background-color: black;
}
`   ;
}

// generate and display boxed letters of the alphabet
function letterBlocks() {
    let letters = Array.from("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    let cssText = "";
    let html = ""
    let blueBoost = document.getElementById("boost").checked;
    letters.forEach( (letter, i, a) => {
       cssText += letterCSS( letter, i, a.length, blueBoost);
       html  += ` <span class="letter ${letter}">${letter}<\/span> `;
    });
    let style = document.createElement("style");
    style.textContent = cssText;
    document.body.appendChild(style);
    let p = document.getElementById("blocks");
    p.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```css
#blocks {
  line-height: 2.5rem;
}
.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-width: 0.125rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="letterBlocks()">Generate Letter Blocks</button><label>
- optionally lighten colors near pure blue:<input type="checkbox" id="boost">
</label>
<p id="blocks"></p>
```

Letter colors start out with full saturation and 50% lightness. Check the option box and click the button to adjust colors close to blue by increasing lightness and decreasing saturation.

- "Close to blue" is hard coded to mean within 25 degree units of hue value `240`,
- The maximum adjustment amount is set by `gain` to `20` percentage units,
- Demonstration code. Real code and adjustment values would be altered on a case by case basis depending on why and how color adjustments are being made.

Comment: Wow, this explanation blew my mind over the rooftop, thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 22):

By randomizing only the hue, it's faster.

[HSLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) colors are a composition of ***Hue, Saturation, Lightness and Alpha.***

Adjust the Lightness `eq: 72%` to adjust the whole pastel set.

```js
function randomHSLA(){
    return `hsla(${~~(360 * Math.random())}, 70%,  72%, 0.8)`
}

rdm.onclick = () => document.body.style.background = randomHSLA()
rdm.click()
```

```html
<button id="rdm">Random pastel color!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could choose among lighter colours by appropriately setting the background-color property using rgb. 
rgb(0,0,0) is black, while rgb(255,255,255) is white. You could therefore use random values which are closer to (but not higher than) 255.
An example (using JQuery):

```
 var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
 var colorQ = "rgb(" + (215 - rand * 3) + "," + (185 - rand * 5) + "," + (185 - rand * 10) + " )"; 
 $("body").css("background-color", colorQ);
```

You can play around with the values until you find the colours that you prefer - keep in mind that the closer the 3 rgb values are to each other, the closer your colour will be to grey. E.g. rgb(100,100,100), rgb(221,221,221) and rgb(133,133,133) are all shades of grey. What changes is how light your grey will be.