# Javascript - Generate Random Pastel HEX/RGBA Color

Tags: javascript

I have the following method

```
export const generateRandomColor = () => {
  const letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  let color = "#";

  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  }

  return color;
};
```

which generates random colors. I am using this function to get the colors of my PieChart, and definitely, it is not elegant at all to see colors of different types (light, dark, pastels...) mixed.

How can I only generate random PASTEL colors in JS (HEX or RGBA)?

Comment: If hex or rgba is fine, would hsl also be? It's just as supported by CSS...

Comment: @AKX I am working on React Native. Not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a range of color with pastel ton like, you can generate each canal with minimal value of 127:

```js
generatePastelColor = () => {
  let R = Math.floor((Math.random() * 127) + 127);
  let G = Math.floor((Math.random() * 127) + 127);
  let B = Math.floor((Math.random() * 127) + 127);
  
  let rgb = (R << 16) + (G << 8) + B;
  return `#${rgb.toString(16)}`;      
}

document.querySelectorAll('#palette div').forEach( elem => {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = generatePastelColor();
});
```

```css
#palette {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#palette > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="palette">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

React Native [seems to support hsl](https://reactnative.dev/docs/colors#hue-saturation-lightness-hsl) according to the docs.
If that works for you, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43195379/15347906) answer may be of some help.